# How to add an Image Button over surface view?

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to add an Imagebutton but it wasn't working because I was using surface view for my game panel. so I did this(code below) but it don't work so i don't know what to do. Please help

```js
public class settingsMenu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        FrameLayout game = new FrameLayout(this);
        GamePanel gameView = new GamePanel (this);

        ImageButton myButton = new ImageButton(this);


        myButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.settings);


        RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        myLayout.addView(myButton, buttonParams);

        game.addView(gameView);
        game.addView(myLayout);

        setContentView(game);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GamePanel.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just combine this two code:

first code:

```
public class settingsMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        FrameLayout game = new FrameLayout(this);


        ImageButton myButton = new ImageButton(this);
        ImageButton myButton2 = new ImageButton(this);

        myButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        myButton2.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo);

        RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        myLayout.addView(myButton2, buttonParams);
        myLayout.addView(myButton, buttonParams);


        game.addView(myLayout);

        setContentView(game);

    }

}
```

Now you exchange this:

```
myLayout.addView(myButton2, buttonParams);

myLayout.addView(myButton, buttonParams);
```

To

```
myLayout.addView(myButton2, buttonParams);

myLayout.addView(myButton, buttonParams);
```

> You see that the upper layouts is covered the lower layouts